# 関数に引数を入れた場合、リスト型なら更新されるが、int型だとなぜか更新されない。

Tags: flutter, dart

このコードではリストを引数に入れたaFunc関数でaの値が更新されますが、intを引数に入れたbFunc関数でbの値が更新されません。これはなぜでしょうか？

また、returnで返すやり方や、bの引数を削除する以外でbの値を更新するやり方はありませんか？アドバイスあればお願いします。

```dart
final a = [1];
var b = 1;
void aFunc(List<int> a_arg){
//  a.first = 3;
  a_arg[0] = 3;
}

void bFunc(int b_arg){
  b_arg = 3;
}

void main() {
  aFunc(a);
  print(a); // [3]
  bFunc(b); 
  print(b); // 1
}
```

Comment: `aFunc` および `bFunc` の中で `a` と `a_arg` を、`b` と `b_arg` を間違ってらっしゃいませんでしょうか。このプログラムだと `print(b)` は `3` を出力します。

Comment: ご指摘していただき大変ありがとうございます。修正しました。

Comment: `aFunc` の方は変更されていませんでしたがこれで想定通りでしょうか？

Comment: またまたご指摘ありがとうございます。修正しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

イメージとしては、引数に渡したオブジェクトは関数で使われる際に新しくコピーされているように考えてください。その上で、引数として渡しているオブジェクトが、データそのものなのか、データの在りかを指し示しているポインターのようなものなのかを意識してください。

`a = [1]` としたとき、この `a` は「リスト」であり、リストの要素の在りかを保持しているオブジェクトです。このため `a` が `a_arg` にコピーされようが `a[0]` と `a_arg[0]` は同じ場所を指し示すので、`a_arg[0]` を更新すると `a[0]` も更新されます。

一方 `b = 1` としたとき、この `b` は `1` というデータそのものなので、これがコピーされた `b_arg` は `b` とは別に `1` というデータを保持します。このため `b_arg` を更新しても `b` は更新されません。

したがって、質問者さんがなさいたいように `b` を `b_arg` への書き込みによって更新したいのであれば、`b` を単なる `int` 型の変数とするのではなくて、クラスで囲むという方法はあります。ありますが、今回のようなシンプルな例では `return` を使って結果を返す方が分かりやすいだろうと思います。

これは Dart が関数の呼び出しについて値渡し　(pass-by-value) を採用しているため起こる挙動です。より詳しくは、同じような現象が起こる Java での説明が参考になるかと思います。例: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480/5989200

Comment: DartではListが引数に渡るときは参照渡し、String,integerが引数に渡るときは値渡しになるという理解で問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: いいえ、自分は全て値渡しになっていると解釈する方が合理的という立場です。このあたり若干用語の混乱が見られるのですが、List の場合は値への参照（ポインター）という値が渡されていると解釈する方が統一的でしょう。（このコメントでなぜ曖昧な書き方をしているかというと、私の知る限り Dart のドキュメントに明示的に値渡しだと書いている箇所が無いためです……。）