# 文字列や数値を引数に取った場合に値渡しではなく、参照渡しで実行できるようにしたい。

Tags: flutter, dart

[関数に引数を入れた場合、リスト型なら更新されるが、int型だとなぜか更新されない。](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/84107/%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0%e3%81%ab%e5%bc%95%e6%95%b0%e3%82%92%e5%85%a5%e3%82%8c%e3%81%9f%e5%a0%b4%e5%90%88-%e3%83%aa%e3%82%b9%e3%83%88%e5%9e%8b%e3%81%aa%e3%82%89%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%82%8b%e3%81%8c-int%e5%9e%8b%e3%81%a0%e3%81%a8%e3%81%aa%e3%81%9c%e3%81%8b%e6%9b%b4%e6%96%b0%e3%81%95%e3%82%8c%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

上記の記事からdartで文字列を引数に入れた状態で実行すると値渡しになることが分かりました。
上記の結果を参照渡しにして、B().bを6にすることは可能でしょうか？

```dart
class B {
  var b = 3;
  
  void bMethod(int b_arg){
    b_arg = 6;
  }
}

void main() {
  B().bMethod(B().b);
  print(B().b); // 3
}
```

Comment: 要望とは合ってないかもしれませんが、これらの記事が参考になるのでは？ [Is there a way to pass a primitive parameter by reference in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18258267/9014308), [Flutter function parameter pass by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55158646/9014308)

Comment: こちらのご質問は、[XY 問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/19110)に陥っているかもしれません。つまり、本当にやりたい目的は別にあるのに、解決法を決め打ちした上で困ったことを質問しているせいで、より目的に沿った回答が集まりづらい構造になってしまっているかもしれません。具体的には今回の疑問はもしかするとそもそもクラスを使わない方法の方が簡潔かもしれないと考えています（[参考](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members)）。既に質問者さんの疑問点は解消されているようなので追加のアクションは不要ですが、もし次に質問なさる際は、その疑問に至った経緯も書いてくださると、より助かる回答が投稿できるかもしれないです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

クラスであれば、参照渡しなので、bMethodにクラスごと渡しています。

```dart
class B {
  var b = 3;
  
  void bMethod(B b){
    b.b = 6;
  }
}

void main() {
  var b = B();
  b.bMethod(b);
  print(b.b);
}
```

質問者さんがあげたコードだとインスタンス化しても、変数にいれていないので、うまくうごきませんね。

`static`を使ったコードもありますが、これは使いどころがかなり限られてくるので、完全に理解していなければ、使用しない方がいいと思います。

```dart
class B {
  static var b = 3;
  
  static void bMethod(){
    B.b = 6;
  }
}

void main() {
  print(B.b);
  B.bMethod();
  print(B.b);
}
```

他の例

```dart
class B {
  var value = 3;
  
  void changeValue(){
    value = 6;
  }
}

void main() {
  var b = B();
  print(b.value);
  b.changeValue();
  print(b.value);
}
```

Comment: +1。追加で、`static` を利用したコードに注意が必要な部分についての補足コメントです：たとえば Effective Dart には「`static` なメンバーしかいないクラスを作るのはやめよう」と載っています。Dart ではトップレベルのスコープでも変数を定義できるからです https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-a-class-that-contains-only-static-members

Answer (score 1):

もちろん可能です、ちょっとコードを変えればね。

staticを使います：

```
class B {
  static var b = 3;
  
  void bMethod(int b_arg){
    B.b = 6;
  }
}

void main() {
  B().bMethod(B().b);
  print(B().b); // 6
}
```

ただこれだけ。